# How to parse arabic pdf with Tika

Tags: solr, arabic, apache-tika

I've installed tika with solr , and it's working well for arabic pdf , is there any tutorial to make this happen , I've seen a similar question to this and the solution was to include ICU4J.jar , but I don't now what does it mean

Comment: What's the question? You say "*it's working well for arabic pdf*" so I'm not sure what isn't working and what you need help with?

Comment: It's Working for other document format such as doc , odt etc ... but for pdf it doesn't extract arabic well , I think they have found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834401/solr-for-arabic , but I'm newbie with Java .

Answer (score 1):

ICU4J can be downloaded here: http://site.icu-project.org/download

Comment: THank for your response , but how to install it ??

Comment: WEB-INF/lib is the standard place for additional libraries (jar files) in a web application (like Solr). If you are running the Solr war file, then look for a shared library directory for your servlet container (probably Tomcat or Jetty).

Comment: unfortunatly I'm a PHP programer and I'm not using tomcat , instead I'm using apache2 , with apachesolr as a server. Any detailed Howto will be so much apriciated, Thanks for your reply

Comment: Apache Solr is a web application written in Java. It is installed in a servlet container, usually Jetty or Tomcat. If you are going to use Solr, you will need to learn the basics of configuring Java webapps.

Comment: Hi sel_space, have you been able to get this working? Did you understand how you can include ICU4J? I am struggling with this as well....